# jQuery Remove by id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am adding test in a fieldset and while I can add them, I am unsure how to write the correct function to remove them. I had it working in javascript but was asked to write it using JQuery and cannot seem to make it work. All example I have researched don't seem to work with my original cloning function which builds a remove button in it. The fieldsets also duplicate and I have the code working for that already, just need a little help with this remove event function.

Here it the javascript/jquery:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;

var i = 0;
var original = document.getElementById('dataTes');

function duplicate() {
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
    clone.id = "dataTes" + ++i; // there can only be one element with an ID
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}

function remove(){

}
```

Here is the html :

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Test</legend>
<input type="submit" class="button" id = "button" value="+" onlick="duplicate()" title = "#">
<input type="submit" class="button" id = "button" value="-" onlick="remove()" title = "#">
<div id="dataTes">
<table align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:10px;" width="97%">
    <tr>
        <td width="100px">Test</td>
        <td width="2px">:</td>
        <td width="2px"><input type="text" name="usrname"></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="button" id = "add" value="+" onClick="addRow('#')" title = "#">
            <input type="submit" class="button" id = "add" value="-" onClick="deleteRow('#')" title = "#">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <table align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:5px;margin-left:40px;" width="97%">
        <tr>
            <td width="2px"></td>
            <td width="100px">Fill</td>
            <td width="2px">:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="usrname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="2px"></td>
            <td width="100px">Fill</td>
            <td width="2px">:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="usrname"></td>
        </tr>
        <table id="dataID" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:40px;" width="97%">
            <tr>
                <td width="2px"></td>
                <td width="100px">Fill</td>
                <td width="2px">:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="usrname">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </table>


</table>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting visibility?

Comment: Yes, I tried @AndrewL.

Comment: Question 1: This can be done without the id `dataTes`, is there a specific reason for using Id? Question 2: Do you realise your HTML is horribly invalid? `table` is not a valid child of `table`. If you are using a table within a table (which by the way is generally a bad practice) it needs to be in a `td` which of course needs to be in a `tr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quick and complete solution. Remove your inline functions to elements `add` and `remove` buttons and attach event to their `id` as below:

```js
var id = 0; //global id to create unique id

$(document).ready(function() {
  //attach click event to element/button with id add and remove
  $("#add,#remove").on('click', function() {
    var currentElemID = $(this).attr('id'); //get the element clicked

    if (currentElemID == "add") { //if it is add elem
      var cloneParent = $("#dataTes").clone(); //clone the dataTes element
      id=$("div[id^=dataTes]").length;//get the count of dataTes element
      //it will be always more than last count each time
      cloneParent.find('[id]').each(function() {
       //loop through each element which has id attribute in cloned set and replace them 
       //with incremented value
        var $el = $(this); //get the element
        $el.attr('id', $el.attr('id') + id);
        //ids would now be add1,add2 etc.,
      });
      cloneParent.attr('id', cloneParent.attr('id') + id);//replace cloneParent id
      cloneParent.appendTo('fieldset');//append the element to fieldset
      $("#remove").show();//show remove button only if there is more than one dataTes element
    } else {
      $("div[id^=dataTes]:last").remove();
      //just remove the last dataTes
      //[id^=dataTes]:last annotates remove last div whose id begins with dataTes
      //remember we have id like dataTes1,dataTes2 etc
      if($("div[id^=dataTes]").length==1){
         //check if only one element is present
         $("#remove").hide();//if yes hide the remove button
      }
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Test</legend>
  <input type="submit" class="button" id="add" value="+" title="#">
  <input type="submit" class="button" id="remove" value="-" style="display:none;" title="#">

  <!--hide the remove button with display:none initially-->

  <div id="dataTes">
    <table align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:10px;" width="97%">
      <tr>
        <td width="100px">Test</td>
        <td width="2px">:</td>
        <td width="2px">
          <input type="text" name="usrname">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="submit" class="button" id="add" value="+" title="#">
          <input type="submit" class="button" id="sub" value="-" title="#">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <table align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:5px;margin-left:40px;" width="97%">
        <tr>
          <td width="2px"></td>
          <td width="100px">Fill</td>
          <td width="2px">:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="usrname">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="2px"></td>
          <td width="100px">Fill</td>
          <td width="2px">:</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="usrname">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <table id="dataID" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;margin-left:40px;" width="97%">
          <tr>
            <td width="2px"></td>
            <td width="100px">Fill</td>
            <td width="2px">:</td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" name="usrname">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </table>


    </table>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Explained line by line as comments. Do let me know if this confuses you.

Comment: I would probably not increment and decrement `id` but set it based on the count of "dataTes" divs. E.g `id= $("div[id^=dataTes]").length + 1`.

Comment: @JonP Agreed and changed accordingly.. :)

Comment: Thanks @GuruprasadRao , how if i want to add that `appendto()` into new `div` that have id `id="result"`

Comment: just replace `fieldset` with `#result`. .That's it.. :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Rename the duplicate IDs on the buttons (originally both `id="button"`).

```
<input type="submit" class="button" id = "button_duplicate" value="+" onlick="duplicate()" title = "#">
<input type="submit" class="button" id = "button_remove" value="-" onlick="remove()" title = "#">
```

2) Bind the `duplicate()` and `remove()` functions on correct buttons. Instead of the `document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;`

```
$("#button_duplicate").click(function(){
    duplicate();
});
$("#button_remove").click(function(){
    remove();
});
```

3) The remove function:

```
function remove(){
    if($("#dataTes" + i).length > 0){
        $("#dataTes" + i).remove();
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

value of i will be in the context. So you can get the id of the element and remove it. Then decrement i. Try this:

**EDIT**(corrected code):

```
function remove(){
    var elId = "dataTes" + i;
    var element = document.getElementById(elId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    i--;
}
```

also first, you need to change id of the button in your html code.

```
<input type="submit" class="button1" id = "add" value="-" onClick="deleteRow('#')" title = "#">
```

and in javascript, it should be:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = remove;
```